# What is the difference between "hide" and "hide out"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me what the difference between *hide* and *hide out* is? For example:

> The guy is **hiding** from the police because he has stolen a car.
>
> The guy is **hiding out** from the police because he has stolen a car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context they are equivalent.

I think "to hide out" has a specific connotation of a person trying to avoid pursuers (like the police), so the subject must be doing the hiding. While "to hide" can be used in exactly this way, it has many other usages. For example, you can use it as a transitive verb:

> I hide the cookies from the children.

But you cannot use "hide out" in this way.